# How to "easily" insert unicode symbol (superscript, degree, etc.. ) in strings using Bokeh and Holoview (for example in title or colorbar)?

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

I need to use Bokeh for my plots and I also need to print different symbol in the title of a plot and colorbar (e.g. °C , kg.m⁻³, kg.m²).

In matplotlib this is easily done using latex type formatting:

```
'$^\circ$C' 
'kg.m$^{-3}$'
'kg.m$^{2}$'
```

But I cannot find an easy way to do that on Bokeh and Holoview except looking into the unicode character table in wikipedia and copy-paste the character I need...

Here is an example of code in Matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

string = '$^\circ$C' + '  ' + 'kg.m$^{-3}$' + '   ' + 'kg.m$^{2}$'
xs = range(-10,11)
ys = [100-x**2 for x in xs]
pl=plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.title(string)
```

[image: Matplotlib example]

If I try to do the same with Holoview:

```py
curve = hv.Curve((xs, ys), label=string)
curve
```

I got:

[image: Bokeh plot with Latex-like string formatting]

The only way I found to get something similar is to manually copy-paste the individual symbols from a unicode table in my scripts:

```py
string = '°C' + '  ' + 'kg.m⁻³'+ '   ' + 'kg.m²'
xs = range(-10,11)
ys = [100-x**2 for x in xs]
curve = hv.Curve((xs, ys), label=string)
curve
```

[image: Bokeh plot with copy-paste unicode characters in the string]

Does anyone know a better solution that manually copy-pasting the unicode characters I need?

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh 2.4 adds support for LaTeX (and MathML) to some elements in Bokeh. Currently, you can use LaTeX on axis labels, tick labels, div widgets, and paragraph widgets. LaTeX support for more elements (including titles) should be added soon. For more information about the new math text feature and how to use them, see the [Bokeh 2.4 release blogpost](https://blog.bokeh.org/bokeh-2-4-6f8a842dfb4f), the new [blackbody radiation example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/latex_blackbody_radiation.html), and the [Bokeh user guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#adding-mathematical-notations)!

[image]